# Copy template document to folder via contextual menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

We use Google Drive to store our team's documents in the cloud.  Some of those documents include templates that we use repeatedly in multiple client files.

Currently, we either make a copy from **File** > **Make a copy** or simply make a copy in the template's folder and then drag and drop it in the folder it needs to be in.

What would be much easier is a contextual menu item when you right click on the destination folder that makes a copy in that folder of your desired template.  Is there anyway to accomplish this?  I'm open to any solutions, whether extensions, scripts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the link that you share with others to make them copy the doc when they click on the link. Replace the word “edit” at the end with “copy”. For example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PG2XSWTAvRyehHAslqt5tiJQ_noeucAMjwA_1tZi0ns/copy

When anyone with access to the spreadsheet opens that link, they’ll immediately be prompted to make a copy:

[image: copy]

Comment: Two immediate issues come to mind with this solution and our use case.  (1) Our users all have access to the folders that contain the templates directly, so no one is using links to get to them, and switching to a link-based system would seem to raise various other issues.  (2) You still need to navigate to the appropriate folder to save the copy, which is one of the things I was hoping to avoid by adding it to the contextual menu.

Comment: Can you not restrict the templates to view-only access, which would force users to copy it?

Comment: Sure, but that would still require to navigate through our file structure from the template to the folder, instead of just being able to add it to the folder (where they're usually going to be anyway).

Comment: Yes, I also find the default location for new files (as the root directory) annoying and time-consuming.